# Translate cURL headers command to python-requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I need to pass a POST containing a token to a website to get an auth key, I've done it successfully using cURL with this statement:

`curl -D - --request POST https://login.website.com/g/aaa/authorize --data-urlencode token=[TOKEN]`

However, I cannot seem to get the same outcome using the Python requests module:

`auth_token = requests.post('https://login.website.com/g/aaa/authorize', data=token)`

`auth_token.text` just gives me `'Unauthorized'`

I've tried passing the data kawrg as :

- straight JSON
- a string
- adding `token=` to the beginning of the string
- using `params` instead of data and passing it JSON (this gets me `unexpected argument: {"token" : "value....."}`)

What is the significance of `-D` and `--data-urlencode` (as opposed to just `--data`) in this case, should I be trying to dump a header as an argument into the `requests.post()`?

*ЕDIT:*
In the cURL output, the auth_key also is printed before any of the json starts:

```
Set-Cookie: auth_key=[auth_key]; Domain=.website.com; expires=Fri, 30-Sep-2016 01:41:09 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=14399; Path=/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, `requests.json()` needed to be used instead of `json.dumps(data)`, the latter is improperly formatted, so this code worked out fine:

```
s.token = requests.post(url, data=data)
s.recieved = s.token.json()
t = requests.post(url, data=s.recieved)
```